# Given a 1xn array with a specific order how do you sort a randomly ordered 1xn array to fit the first array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an 1xn size array where order and index position matters. Could be large n.

```
recipe = ['flour', 'eggs', 'apples', 'cinnamon', 'baking powder', 'sugar']
```

suppose I have a function that returns two randomly ordered arrays.

`another_recipe_values = [ 2, 4, 6 ]`

where the values corresponds to the following keys in a separate 1xn array

`another_recipe_keys = [ 'apples', 'sugar', 'eggs']`

Whats an elegant way or fast way to sort both arrays to fit/match n-dimensions in the first array?

like this

```
new_recipe_values = [ 0, 6, 2, 0, 0, 4] 
new_recipe_keys = [ null, 'eggs', 'apples', null, null, 'sugar']
```

*update edited the output variables.

Comment: what means sorting?

Comment: Using Map function

Comment: I'd prefer `recipe` to be a hashmap for ingredient->index.

Comment: yes that's correct.

Comment: @gurvinder372 0-based index

Comment: @Nina Scholz Hi nina not sure what you mean by sorting but I mean that is is grouped in a specific order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go for

```
const recipe = ['flour', 'eggs', 'apples', 'cinnamon', 'baking powder', 'sugar']

let another_recipe_values = [ 2, 4, 6 ];
let another_recipe_keys = [ 'apples', 'sugar', 'eggs']

const indices = recipe.map(ingredient => another_recipe_keys.indexOf(ingredient));

another_recipe_values = indices.map(i => i<0 ? 0 : another_recipe_values[i]);
another_recipe_keys = indices.map(i => i<0 ? null : another_recipe_keys[i]);
```

A better (faster, simpler) option might be

```
const ordered_ingredients = ['flour', 'eggs', 'apples', 'cinnamon', 'baking powder', 'sugar']
const another_recipe = {
    apples: 2,
    sugar: 4,
    eggs: 6
};
const another_recipe_values = ordered_ingredients.map(ing =>
    ing in another_recipe ? another_recipe[ing] : 0
);
const another_recipe_keys = ordered_ingredients.map(ing =>
    ing in another_recipe ? ing : null
);
```

You can also build the `another_recipe` object dynamically from your two arrays.

Comment: @gurvinder372 Oh right, the OP had used the same variable names for the inputs and the result. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `map()` function and set null the positions where there is a `0` value.

`recipe.map((value, index) => recipe_values[index] != 0? value: null)`

```js
var recipe = ['flour', 'eggs', 'apples', 'cinnamon', 'baking powder', 'sugar']

var recipe_values = [ 0, 6, 2, 0, 0, 4] 

var result = recipe.map((value, index) => recipe_values[index] != 0? value: null)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply return `null` where the value is `0` in `another_recipe_values` else use that value as index from recipes

```js
var recipe = ['flour', 'eggs', 'apples', 'cinnamon', 'baking powder', 'sugar'];
var another_recipe_values = [0, 6, 2, 0, 0, 4];
var output = another_recipe_values.map((s, i) => s ? recipe[i] : null);

console.log(output);
```